# Big O and Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, computer-science

Suppose an algorithm is known to be O(N<sup>2</sup>) and solving a problem of size M takes 5 minutes. About how long will it take to solve a problem of size 4M?

Is it as simple as ...

M=5min
4M=20min

?

Comment: You can not calculate the real time consumption. The big O is just an approximation, but you can estimate that, with size 4M, the time is 5 * (4*4) = 80min

Comment: The key here is that the time required increases with the square of the number of items. So twice as many items will take four times as long (i.e. 2^2). Four times as many items will take 16 times as long (4^2). 10 times as many items will take 100 times as long (10^2), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Big O` is just an approximation you can not compute the real time but yes you can have some estimation. In your case it would be

```
1 M ~ 5 min
4 M ~ 5 *(4*4) min ~ 80 min.
```

**Note : I used symbol `~` to show approximation.**

O(N^2) => problem with size N will take approximately N^2 time

M will take approximately M^2 time

```
O(M)~ O(1M) 
=> 1^2*M^2 
=> M^2 
=> 5 min


O(4M) ~ (4M)^2 
=> 4^2*M^2 
=> 16*M^2 
=> 16*5 
=> 80 min
```

Comment: Usually when the reference number is relatively large, the O approximation is pretty good.  With small numbers, however, things tend to not follow the approximation.  So if `M` is small for the algorithm (e.g. a *10*-line computer program or a database with *50* entries), the approximation for `4M` is unlikely to hold.

Comment: How to generalize the way you solved the problem (i.e. size A = X minutes, size B = ? minutes) isn't immediately obvious - it might be wise to add some details on this.

Comment: I don't understand why you did the calculation (4*4).

Comment: @user3534193 I have added the explanation.

Comment: @user3534193 Could you please accept the answer if you are satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

If the complexity is O(N^2), this means the time for a problem of size N is roughly k*N^2 for some fixed but unknown value of k.

If you represent the approximate time to run the algorithm on a problem of size N as T(N), then mathematically you have this:

```
T(N)   = k*N^2
T(M)   = k*M^2
T(M)   = 5 minutes
T(4*M) = k*(4*M)^2 
       = 16*k*M^2 
       = 16*T(M)
       = 80 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, not necesarily.

When we say that a problem's time complexity is O(N<sup>2</sup>), what that means is that given a problem of size *N*, the time it takes to run conforms roughly to some equation of the form *a + bN + cN<sup>2</sup>*, where a, b, and c are unknown coefficients.

This does mean that *eventually* the *N<sup>2</sup>* term will dominate the run-time.  But eventually might be a long time away.  There might be a large constant set-up time built in (that is, *a* in the formula above is big), such that 4 of the 5 minutes of your hypothetical scenario don't vary with problem size.  In that case, perhaps a problem of size 4M might take less than twice as long to run.

Situations along these lines can happen frequently with algorithms that involve hashing (such as some associative array implementations), particularly if a slow hash function such as SHA2 is being used.  Which is why for small collections of elements searching a simple array to see if it contains an element might be faster than searching a hash table, even though searching an array is O(N) and searching a hash set is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is simple, but your calculation is wrong.

What you have calculated is a linear growth, e.g. something of growth of O(n) e.g. if some input takes five minutes, you double the size of your input, then time spend is twice that time. You state that your algorithm run in O(n^2) which is exponential growth.

So your calculation would look like this:

```
M^2 = 5 minutes <=> 
M = sqrt(5) = 2.23607 (approx)
```

so

```
(4M)^2 = (4*2.23607)^2 = 80 minutes
```

Which is exponential growth.

This is also why you never talk about specific run times in computer science. Whether something takes 5 minutes or 5 hours is not interesting. What is interesting is ***what happens when we change the size of the input***. Because when we implement algorithms we want something that runs faster, ***no matter what computer is used for testing*** when the size of the input moves towards ***infinite***.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct in case you have `O(n)`, but we have `O(n^2)` which means you need to square the constant

```
T(M) = (M)^2 = M^2 = 5 minutes

T(4M) = (4 * M)^2 = 4^2 * M^2 = 16 * M^2

Substitute: M^2 = 5 minutes

T(4M) = 16 * M^2 = 16 * 5 minutes

T(4M) = 80 minutes
```